# click into a rect within html5 svg application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html5-canvas

i have a web application in which i'm using `svg` and `Raphael` library:

```
 workflowEditor.show();
     var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
     for (var a = 0; a < myList.length; a++) {
         myList[a].addEventListener("OnClick", function () {
            var index = workflowEditor.getElementIndex(myList[a]);
            alert(index);

         }, true);
     }
```

i tried to handle the event click into a rectangle but it failed.

What is the problem?How can i fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to show it in a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
myList[a].addEventListener("OnClick", function () {
```

to

```
myList[a].addEventListener("click", function () {
```